# Cakephp 2.4 Trying to use CakeResponse in Component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm trying to use the CakeResponse to create and download a file from a string in one of my  Components (App/Controller/Component) but I got this error

```
Call to a member function body() on a non-object
```

with the code below

```
$this->response->body("toto");
$this->response->download("titi.txt");
return $this->response;
```

How can I access to the CakeResponse from a component ?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: download() - as clearly documented - just sets the headers. the end of the dispatcher cycle will then send them and this way render the response ready for download.

Comment: Your edit should be another question altogether (and only post it after doing a through search and debug of the problem). If you add the question "download doesn't work" to the previous one, mark's answer will have to be edited and/or deleted because it must address another problem that has little to do with the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesnt the error tell you whats wrong?
It clearly says that the object is not available this way.

Usually, you would try to access it via the controller object inside the component callbacks:

```
public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
    $controller->response->body(...);
    ...
}
```

etc

If you need it in other methods you can pass it to local attribute in initialize() and reuse it then later:

```
$this->Controller = $controller;
```

Comment: Yes, I understood the error, my question was more like "How can I access at the CakeResponse within a component", sorry. Now the error is gone, thank to you, but nothing happen. I'll update my question.